# Getting coordinates for geojson

Tags: svg, dictionary, tiff, geojson, tilemill

I have a geotiff that I have been working with in tilemill and I would like to select portions (buildings) in the map and create new layers as geojson objects. My issue is I don't know how to get the coordinates to create the objects!

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html#_choropleth

this is a link to what I'm trying to do with states I just need the step where the coordinates are gotten because it doesn't seem to be in this document, they just give a shout to the guy who defined them. If anyone has done something similar to this, please give me a shout!

**Update**

I am not looking for the coordinates to the US, I have a fictional map that I am working from.

Comment: Have you looked into GEOIP, they have free csv files to download with coordinates across the US ?

Comment: Ah I'm not doing the US though I have created a fictional map and was looking to recreate what they have done with the states using my map

Answer (score 0):

TileMill is a tool for visualizing data and creating map tiles - it isn't designed for creating or digitizing tasks. You'll want to export your map to [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) (or another MBTiles-supporting server), and use a tool like Mapbox's map editor or [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) to create GeoJSON overlays on top of it.